# User-friendly way to ask about locking the iPhone screen

Tags: iphone, user-interface, settings

I have an app where it will be a setting whether or not to allow the screen to auto-lock during idle periods.

My question:  what's the user-friendly (and user-understandable) way to present the option.  It'll be in a `UITableView` with a `UISwitch`, so i'll look somewhat like:
[image]

What's the best language to use?
Keep screen on
Prevent auto-lock

Is there a common-practice to adhere to?

Something else?

Comment: This question is better suited for UX.stackexchange.

Comment: You're probably right -- I had a feeling there might be something like that, but I didn't know what it was.  Should I close the question here?

Comment: I agree, link your account with UX stack-exchange and post again - it's a good question, and I couldn't see that this has been asked on that site? Related, does this translate well, when localizing apps?

Comment: wait for a mod to do that. I flagged the question, shouldn't be long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I certainly like "Disable Auto-Lock" with a `UISwitch`, like you have in your screenshot. I've seen this used in a number of apps, and it makes sense to me.